# exporting multiple tables to multiple sheets of same excel files using displaytag

Tags: spring, displaytag

I know that we can export a table to excel using displaytag in spring.But i need to export multiple tables in same excel file as different excel sheets using the displaytag.Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display tag does not support exporting multiple tables into the same file at the same time.

You will have to write your own export class.

Check Displaytag src.  It custom export examples as HTML or using iText.